# Как переделать HTML страницу на ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

У меня есть страница разработанная при помощи HTML+CSS+JavaScript. На странице имеются кнопки, инпуты и пр. Нужна связать эти элементы с кодом. Я новичок в asp.net поэтому многих вещей незнаю. Не могли бы подсказать, как можно простым путем переделать страницу под asp.net?

Answer (score 4):

[@skyboy](/users/12240/skyboy), HTML+CSS+JavaScript - это клиентская сторона. ASP - это значит, что добавляется некая серверная функциональность в код (логику кода), т.е. страница (как базовая единица информации) становится продуктом некоей логики. А так, то если просто переименовать расширение файла с .html на .asp(x), то ничего не изменится и будет работать.
"Связать с кодом" - такое понятия является растяжимым, как наша Вселенная. "Связать" и "Получить" можно миллионы разных данных, причем из разных элементов. Поэтому, мой совет - учите матчасть и не отвлекайтесь на Хэшкод с такими **абстрактными** вопросами. На такой вопрос не получить никакого ответа, я гарантирую.